# How to download private app published to organization's admin console

Tags: android

I have followed this [guide](https://apps.google.com/supportwidget/articlehome?hl=en&article_url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.google.com%2Fa%2Fanswer%2F2494992%3Fhl%3Den&assistant_id=generic-unu&product_context=2494992&product_name=UnuFlow&trigger_context=a) (option 1) and published a android app to my organization admin console and made it available to the entire organization.

Surprisingly, there is no information on the entire internet on how people within the organization can download their private app. If you try to search it they only talk about how to publish it and there is no information on how to install it to their phone at all.

Just try my luck here and thanks in advance to anyone on stack who ever need to use their organization's app.

Comment: The linke page mentions that those apps will be available in the [managed Google Play store](http://play.google.com/work).

Comment: Found them in the mysterious Work App section.